# Why `bootstrap.liftweb.Boot` of Liftweb is a class, other than an object?

Tags: class, scala, object, lift

In lift application:

```
package bootstrap.liftweb

class Boot {
    def boot = {}
}
```

I want to know why `Boot` is a `class` not an `object`? It should be executed only once, so I think `object Boot` is more reasonable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`object Boot` and `class Boot` have no restrictions on how many times `def boot` can be executed just how you do so.

The only thing that may be affected is the instances. `class Boot` can have more than one instance while `object Boot` will be a `static` method. only the object that calls `Boot` will require to be `static`.